# Help reproduce graph from excel

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I would like to reproduce the following graph:

On the horizontal axis I would like to have 8 the question numbers, and I would like to plot two results for each question.

for example

```
questionnumbers<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

result1<-c(0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.9,0.3,0.4,0.8)

result2<-c(0.4,0.9,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.3,0.2)
```

And i'd like to get a graph similar to this:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/chart.tiff

Preferably I'd like to know how to do this in qplot using ggplot2

Comment: I suggest you study the excellent examples at the ggplot2 website, in particular the page describing `geom_line` http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_line.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

qs <- data.frame(
  questionnumbers = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  result1 = c(0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.9,0.3,0.4,0.8), 
  result2 = c(0.4,0.9,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.3,0.2)
)

mqs <- melt(qs, id.vars="questionnumbers")

ggplot(mqs, aes(x=questionnumbers, y=value, colour=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

---

Edited.

Your follow-on question asks what is different with your diffferent data set.  The answer is that your grouping variable is continuous, not categorical.  By default, ggplot will group categorical variables together.  If your grouping variable is not categorical, you need to make the grouping variable explicit in the `aes` call in ggplot, as follows `aes(..., group=variable, ...):

```
qs<-data.frame(
    questionnumbers = c("1red","1blue","2red","2blue","3red","3blue","4red","4blue"), 
    Probability=c(0.59,0.60,0.55,0.55,0.60,0.58,0.67,0.68), 
    Chosing.colour=c(0.16,0.21,0.26,0.53,0.84,0.89,0.84,0.947))

mqs <-melt(qs, id.vars="questionnumbers") 
str(mqs)
ggplot(mqs, aes(x=questionnumbers, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: excellent thank you! My only problem is that with another set of data it doesn't work for some reason:

qs<-data.frame(questionnumbers = c("1red","1blue","2red","2blue","3red","3blue","4red","4blue"), Probability=c(0.59,0.60,0.55,0.55,0.60,0.58,0.67,0.68), Chosing.colour=c(0.16,0.21,0.26,0.53,0.84,0.89,0.84,0.947))

mqs <-melt(qs, id.vars="questionnumbers")

 ggplot(mqs, aes(x=questionnumbers, y=value, colour=variable)) + geom_line()
what am I doing differently?

Comment: See my edited answer.  Precis: you need to make the grouping variable explicit since you are using a metric grouping variable.

Comment: thanks a lot! one final thing: is there any way to have 0.5 indicated on the vertical axis? also it seemed to change the order of presenting the bottom questions. It should start with Red but it starts with Blue

Comment: You can specify breaks in your scale by using the `breaks=...` parameter in `scale_y_continuous`.  ggplot orders any categorical variables in alphabetical order.  If you want something else, you need to convert `questionnumbers` into an ordered factor.

Comment: using cut(questionnumbers, ordered_result=true) ?

Comment: @Anrie Ive tried to find it in the documentation but there's no mention of it...http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_line.html

Answer (score 0):

In base graphics it would be...

```
questionnumbers<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
result1<-c(0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.9,0.3,0.4,0.8)
result2<-c(0.4,0.9,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.3,0.2)

plot(questionnumbers, result2, type = 'b', ylim = c(0,0.9), col = 'green', xlab = 'Question Nunbers', ylab = '', main = 'Chart 2', panel.first = grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL))
lines(questionnumbers, result1, col = 'blue', type = 'b')
legend('bottomleft', c('result1','result2'), fill = c('blue', 'green'), cex = 0.8, bty = 'n', horiz = TRUE)
```

(you should really provide a y-axis label)